# jquery mobile - calls firing twice when nav to another page and back

Tags: jquery

I am pretty new to jqm i have tried about 20 different things and have been at this a few hours, the best I can get to work is the following code.

```
$(function() {
$('.load_more').live("click",function() {
//my ajax call here

success: function(htmldat){
    $("#more").remove();
       $("#updates").append(htmldat).listview('refresh');
       $("#more").trigger('create');

}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

What my page does is load 10 records from a database into a list view, I have a button(.load_more) that appends the next ten records to the listview. As soon as I navigate away from the page and come back and click the button it fires twice. I have went through so many suggestions and can't get one to work, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also that code I am loading before the closing body tag on the page I am using it.

EDIT

The following code appears to work although when i replace the alert with my function it wont work, no event is triggered.

```
$(document).delegate("#clickers", "pageinit", function () {
  $(".load_more").off('click').on('click', function () {
    alert("hello");
  });
});
```

When the button is clicked it fetches data and appends it to the listview, when i recreate the button could that be killing the event ?

```
$("#more").remove();
$("#updates").append(htmldat).listview('refresh');
$("#more").trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon reading your edit, it's clear that the issue is definitely with recreating the button. Event handlers get bound to DOM elements that exist when the handlers are created; they don't blanket apply to all later elements with the same id. An easy solution would be to bind the handlers on each create:

```
var recreateButton = function() { 
    $("#more").remove();
    $("#updates").append(htmldat).listview('refresh');
    $("#more").trigger('create');
    $("#more").off('click').on('click', function(){});
}
```

Alternatively, you could just use the onClick event on the button element to call a function each time it is clicked.

Comment: i tried this already but the button only fires once, nothing happens when clicked again, same with the off('click').on method,

Comment: you need to wrap either the ajax or the recreation in a function, your choice which

Comment: i tried adding the function, and called it from onsuccess() the button does get recreated but still not the event handler.

Comment: i called the function using the onclick method and within that function i created the handler $("#clickers").off("click").on( "click", ".load_more", function( e ) {     seems to have done the trick, will test it for a bit, thanks man

Comment: $("#gpsb_launch_attack").unbind("click").click( function(){}); This was not working, was still firing twice, but when i changed this to
$("#gpsb_launch_attack").off("click").on("click", function(){}); Bam it works :) Thanks man